# how do you convert (small) BigNumbers?

Tags: solidity, web3js, bignumber

i created a variable called `startDate` using `now` in a smart contract.

when reading it using `Contract.startDate()` it returns `BigNumber { s: 1, e: 9, c: [ 1530272788 ] }`

how do i convert this to an Interger (or anything else i can work with)? `toNumber()` and `toString()` wont work.

edit: `toNumber()` already worked on "bigger" bugnumbers (with e>10), just not with the bigNumber returned by startDate

Comment: Try `valueOf() ` or `toString() `.

Comment: already said toString() doesnt work. returns `'[object Promise]'  

`
valueOf() returns the same BigNumber again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toNumber()` is right, but it sounds like you have a `Promise` that will resolve to a `BigNumber`. If so, this should work:

```
Contract.startDate().then(date => {
    console.log(date.toNumber());
});
```

Comment: edit: nvm, I somehow copied it wrong. this actually works. thank you!